# Supabase Auth: onAuthStateChange not triggered

Tags: flutter, supabase

I'm trying to implement Google Auth in my app but I can't get it work.

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Sign in"),
              onPressed: (){
                 supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(
                  Provider.google,
                );
              },
            ),
ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Sign out"),
              onPressed: (){
                supabase.auth.signOut();

              },
            ),
 ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Show user"),
              onPressed: (){
                print(supabase.auth.currentUser);


              },
            ),
```

and then listening to Auth change with

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {

      final AuthChangeEvent event = data.event;
      final Session? session = data.session;

      if(event == AuthChangeEvent.signedIn) {
        print("logged");

      }
    });
  }
```

"logged" is never printed, while in the Supabase console I see the log in is done succesfully. Also "Show user" always returns `null` even after log in.

Documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-google#using-the-oauth-flow-for-the-web

Comment: You have to setup deep links in order to complete the OAuth login process. https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter#oauth-login

Comment: "For providers other than Apple or Google" I'm using Google

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this for web? If so, I think you are on the right track. I was having the same issue as you did but I got it working.

If you are NOT doing this for web, I think you are using the wrong API. You should be using `signInWithIdToken`. Source: https://supabase.com/blog/flutter-authentication

Keep this in mind:

- Setting a `redirectTo` on the `signInWithOAuth` function is NOT required for the `onAuthStateChange` callback to be triggered. However, keep in mind that not setting a redirect will cause the Google login flow to redirect to your application's home page. This will basically restart your application and you have to make sure that your flow will still register the `onAuthStateChange` callback again. Personally, this was my issue. I solved it by moving the `onAuthStateChange` callback to a different Widget that was higher in my Widget tree.